# Summation notation

Tags: summation, index

I have the current setup for calculating Allan Deviation:

[image: ADEV]

which was coded as:

```
Sqrt[Total[Differences[y]^2]/(2 (M - 1))]
```

However, after doing some research, overlapping Allan Deviation is what I need to calculate, which looks like:

[image]

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to adjust my code for this change... I attempted to put it in as you see above (in fact, this was done with the math palette), but it runs for a long time, then when I graph the results with `ListLogLogPlot` it gives an empty graph. I am guessing Mathematica doesn't understand the subscript is being used as an index. I searched the Summation documentation, however, it doesn't discuss how to enter the portions of a function.

Here is a copy of the code (which I am sure some of you will recognize, as I asked last week about some of the nuances of working with this function in Mathematica, mapping, tables, etc).

```
WN = WhiteNoiseProcess[NormalDistribution[0, 10]];
\aDev[m_] := 
 Module[{data, points, yBinLst, y, M}, 
  data = RandomFunction[WN, {1, 10000}];
  points = data["Values"];
  yBinLst = Partition[points, m];
  y = Mean /@ yBinLst;
  M = Length[yBinLst];

  Sqrt[Total[Differences[y]^2]/(2 (M - 1))]
  ]
SeedRandom[0];
mValues = Range[2, 5000, 1];
aData = aDev /@ mValues;
ListLogLogPlot[aData]
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Indexed` or `Part` rather than the subscripts in your `Sum`?

Comment: Including code (no matter how messy) for your second image would be nice so we don't have to reenter it manually.

Comment: `Sqrt[(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \((M - 2  m + 1)\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = j\), \((j + m - 1)\)]
\*SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(i + m\)] - 
\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(i\)])\), \(2\)]\)\))/2 m^2 (M - 2 m + 1)]`

Like this?

Also, sorry about that. :/

Comment: Yes, that can be pasted into *Mathematica* and it saves work retyping.

Comment: Does the output in my answer appear to be what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am trying to figure out what exactly is wrong. But, I am fairly certain the problem is in the math, not the code... Now that I have seen how to do it, I am pretty confident I know how to enter the summation correctly now. Thank you!

Comment: There may be faster ways to perform the computation if speed is a limiting factor.  For example you could start from `Differences[y, 1, m]^2`.

Comment: I will give this a shot, thank you so much for taking the time to help. :)

Comment: Is there a way to square just the first inside summation of `{i, j, j + m - 1}` without squaring the outside summation?

Comment: If I understand I can't think of a way to write that with `Sum`.  If you know the output you want for a given `y`, `M`, `m` post a small example and I'll try again to help.

Comment: Actually, I realized what I did wrong, thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you want?

```
aDev2[m_] :=
 Module[{data, points, yBinLst, y, M},
   data = RandomFunction[WN, {1, 10000}];
   points = data["Values"];
   yBinLst = Partition[points, m];
   y = Mean /@ yBinLst;
   M = Length[yBinLst];
   Sum[(y[[i + m]] - y[[i]])^2, {j, 1, M - 2 m + 1}, {i, j, j + m - 1}]/
     2 m^2 (M - 2 m + 1) // Sqrt
]

SeedRandom[0];
mValues = Range[2, 5000, 1];
aData = aDev2 /@ mValues;
ListLogLogPlot[aData]
```

[image]